# prevent accessing of controller directly from url which is in subdirectory in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

This is my controller structute:

```
controllers
  |
  |__ posts
     |
     |__post.php
```

i have removed directory name from the url by changing in the routes.php file

```
$route['post/posts_controller'] = 'posts/post/posts_controller';
```

but now i want if anybody hits the complete url with the directory name i.e. `http://localhost/url_routing/posts/post/posts_controller`
then the page not found should appear.

Comment: Are controller name is "post.php" or posts_controller.php?

Comment: @Punit- post.php is controller name and posts_controller is the method name inside post controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a real problem with CodeIgniter, which can result in a LOT of duplicate content for search engine. The only workaround I found is to overwrite the Router to only use the routes.php and not folders / controllers names.

> application/core/MY_Router.php

```
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    /**
     * Parse Routes
     *
     * Matches any routes that may exist in the config/routes.php file
     * against the URI to determine if the class/method need to be remapped.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    protected function _parse_routes()
    {
        // Turn the segment array into a URI string
        $uri = implode('/', $this->uri->segments);

        // Get HTTP verb
        $http_verb = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ? strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) : 'cli';

        // Loop through the route array looking for wildcards
        foreach ($this->routes as $key => $val)
        {
            // Check if route format is using HTTP verbs
            if (is_array($val))
            {
                $val = array_change_key_case($val, CASE_LOWER);
                if (isset($val[$http_verb]))
                {
                    $val = $val[$http_verb];
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // Convert wildcards to RegEx
            $key = str_replace(array(':any', ':num'), array('[^/]+', '[0-9]+'), $key);
            // Does the RegEx match?

            if (preg_match('#^'.$key.'$#', $uri, $matches))
            {
                // Are we using callbacks to process back-references?
                if ( ! is_string($val) && is_callable($val))
                {
                    // Remove the original string from the matches array.
                    array_shift($matches);

                    // Execute the callback using the values in matches as its parameters.
                    $val = call_user_func_array($val, $matches);
                }
                // Are we using the default routing method for back-references?
                elseif (strpos($val, '$') !== FALSE && strpos($key, '(') !== FALSE)
                {
                    $val = preg_replace('#^'.$key.'$#', $val, $uri);
                }

                $this->_set_request(explode('/', $val));
                return;
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

This will result in CodeIgniter only using your routes.php, so I you still want to use CI routing, then don't use it.

Comment: Thanks Gwendal! I m getting following error : Fatal error: Access level to MY_Router::_parse_routes() must be public (as in class CI_Router).

Comment: @user3653474 using ci 3 ?

Comment: Oh, your tag is ci2... I made it for ci3, so don't know if it'll work. Try to change method to public

Comment: When i include the above in my project then accessing simply other controller and methods shows page not found, will i have to include route of every controller in route.php file or there is something else to deal with it.

Comment: As I said, this makes CI only using the `routes.php`, so maybe it's not the best solution for you.